# Maximum Call Stack error when trying to make new user in Parse JS API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm totally new to the Parse API as well as server side js in general. I'm trying to write a simple function to register a new user when the click the submit button the corresponding form. I commented out all of the jquery pulling the data in the form and just have the function trying to register with a hard code username and password. I also took out my apps keys but they are correct in the original. Here's the  showing the js links.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SitWith - Great Conversations. No Pressure.</title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
    <script src="../js/sitwith.js"></script>

</head>
```

And here's the javascript file.

```
Parse.initialize("App Key", 
  "JS Key");

$('#register').click(function(){

/*    var registerFName = $('#registerFName').val();
    var registerLName = $('#registerLName').val();
    var registerUsername = $('#registerUsername').val();
    var registerEmail = $('#registerEmail').val();
    var resisterPassword = $('#registerPassword').val();*/

  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("username", "MyName");
  user.set("password", "MyPassword");
  /*user.set("email", registerEmail);
  user.set("FName", registerFName);
  user.set("LName", registerLName);*/


  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
      console.log("User created");
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the console error:

parse-1.3.2.min.js:1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Like I said, I'm pretty new to all of this but couldn't find a thread anywhere describing this exact issue with Parse. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Parse documentation, `signUp is a static method` on Parse.User so it should be called a little differently. You also need to pass signUp the username and password.

It should be used as follows

```
Parse.User.signUp(username, password, {}, {
        success: function (user) {
            alert("Yay!");
        },
        error: function (user, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

Also the error you are getting is

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This error is thrown only when the, method calls itself infinitely, in such a case the stacks gets overloaded an throws this exception.

Comment: the "user.signUp" is taken from Parse example. I figured this would work because I've already instantiated user as a new Parse.User earlier in the function. I changed it to just Parse.User.signUp with the parameters as you described them and still get the same error. Also, that the RangeError is referring to the Parse JS CDN file. Any thoughts on why that would be?